# Suspected foul play with a triple of questions

Tags: discussion

A little while ago someone asked (now deleted, but link still here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314572/advice-on-how-i-can-i-publish-my-solution-of-the-riemann-hypothesis?noredirect=1#comment784775_314572), somewhat pretentiously, how they can publish their proof of a 'famous conjecture in analytic number theory'. It is later revealed that the 'famous conjecture' in question is actually RH, and soon after they posted the full 'solution' in the question component. It was downvoted hard, but before I saw the end of it it was deleted.

Just a few days later, this question popped up: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314776/on-some-expression-in-bui-et-als-paper-and-the-riemann-hypothesis

It is extremely likely that both the asker of the question and the user 'YNWA' are the same person, and both are the same person as the original poster of the deleted question. Their posts are virtually identical, and the accepted 'answer' is almost verbatim the 'proof' in the deleted question.

Thus, it seems to me that this is all a somewhat elaborate ruse on the part of the user to get their 'proof' accepted by the mathematical community.

I don't think this kind of behaviour belongs on MO; it attracts the wrong kind of crowd here. I would be very much incensed if people constantly post dubious, two-page 'proofs' of famous conjectures here and ask for approval from professional mathematicians who frequent here.

Is there any official stance on such phenomena, and if there is a policy in place, whether effective enforcement methods are put into place?

Edit: the title refers to a *triple* of questions, and the third one is this (also deleted): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314792/an-integral-involving-log-zetas

Comment: Do you think that downvoting, closing, deleting and flagging are not sufficient to avoid such posts cluttering the site?

Comment: @StefanKohl the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314776/on-some-expression-in-bui-et-als-paper-and-the-riemann-hypothesis is still there, and has 7 upvotes. Typically such a question would be considered in good standing, so I am not sure what we're doing currently is enough

Comment: I don't know how it comes that such question has 7 upvotes. -- Possibly there is some sock puppetry going on there.

Comment: The question is no longer there.

Comment: There was also some sockpuppetry related to recent RH-crankery - not sure if this is the same user... (don't have the relevant deleted questions bookmarked on this computer, can look when I get home)

Comment: Hmm, it might be the same person (under different user identities), since the author of the questions Stanley is referring to has a profile linked to this other MO account https://mathoverflow.net/users/123416/user123416 and a physics.SE account responsible for this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/424247/a-physical-insight-on-the-de-bruijn-newman-constant on the DeBruijn-Newman constant which has the same level of misunderstanding as the deleted "DBN constant" questions on MO...

Comment: It seems that in your first link you [link to a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314572/advice-on-how-i-can-i-publish-my-solution-of-the-riemann-hypothesis?noredirect=1#comment784775_314572) rather than using [link to the question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314572/advice-on-how-i-can-i-publish-my-solution-of-the-riemann-hypothesis). I am not sure whether it is intentional (whether this comment has particular significance) or whether it happened by mistake.

Comment: Also I will add that if your post is mainly about this particular situation, the tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) might be suitable. (See [the tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/specific-question/info) for more details.) However, from the wording of the post it seems that links to the three questions serve merely as an example and you want to discuss this issue in general, not only this particular instance. (In which case, this tag is not needed.)

Comment: @StefanKohl I'm pretty sure I've seen that question in the HNQ, that could also explain the upvotes (especially since the association bonus is enough to upvote but not to downvote).

Comment: I don't have a rigorous proof but I believe it is impossible in principle to machine-, rule- or otherwise automatically/formally recognize and block such cases. On the other hand I believe the community deals with them quite efficiently, with minimal intervention from the moderating team.

Comment: What abou this question? Is it related? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315019/enquiry-on-a-certain-family-of-integrals-and-residue-integration

Comment: @AndrásBátkai Looks like it, and once again we have a new user accout to deal with. Note that this new user mentions the paper of Bui et al which is also referred to in one the questions Stanley noticed: https://mathoverflow.net/posts/314776/

Comment: @YemonChoi That link gets a 404 - is it a typo, or did it get super-deleted?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Typo, sorry: I meant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314776/on-some-expression-in-bui-et-als-paper-and-the-riemann-hypothesis

Comment: @YemonChoi: And what about this answer? https://mathoverflow.net/q/315923

Comment: @AndrásBátkai Yes, seems to be the same person

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316093/is-there-an-analogue-for-the-balazard-et-al-criterion-for-the-generalised-rieman#316093 looks like another one